# python:remove unicode characters

Tags: python, mongodb, unicode

```
import sys
import nltk
import unicodedata
import pymongo
conn = pymongo.Connection('mongodb://localhost:27017')

 def jd_extract():
    try:
        iter = collection.find({},limit=1)
        for item in iter:
             return (item['jd'])


res=jd_extract()
print res
```

prints

```
[u'Software Engineer II', , u' ', , u' ', , u' ', Skills: C#,WPF,SQL , u' ', , u' ', Experience: 3-4.5 Yrs , u' ', , u' ', Job Location:- Gurgaon/Noida , u' ', , u' ', Job Summary: , u' ', The Software Engineer II's role is to develop and manage the application code for a system or part of a project. The Software Engineer II role typically has skills to work with multiple platforms and/or services. , u' ',   , u' ',   , u' \xa0',  , u' ', , u' ', ][u' ', Salary: , u'\n', Not Disclosed by Recruiter , u'\n', , u'\n'][u' ', Industry: , u'\n', IT-Software / Software Services , u'\n', , u'\n'][u' ', Functional Area: , u'\n', IT Software - Application Programming, Maintenance , u'\n', , u'\n'][u' ', Role Category: , u'\n', Programming &amp; Design , u'\n', , u'\n'][u' ', Role: , u'\n', Software Developer , u'\n', , u'\n'][u' ', Keyskills: , u'\n', wpf C# Sql Programming , u'\n', , u'\n'][u' ', Education: , u'\n', 
    UG - Any Graduate - Any Specialization, Graduation Not Required    
     PG - Any Postgraduate - Any Specialization, Post Graduation Not Required     
     Doctorate - Any Doctorate - Any Specialization, Doctorate Not Required      , u'\n', , u'\n']
```

I want to remove unicode characters from res. I tried str(res) but not working.

Comment: `Software Engineer II` is Unicode too. Did you mean *non-ASCII characters* perhaps?

Comment: All your strings only contain ASCII codepoints; what is the problem exactly? Did you meant you needed to encode the unicode values to byte strings? At the very least your data is incomplete; there is no quote before `Skills`, for example, there are empty `,` characters in your output, etc.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to remove any non-ascii character or do you want to turn the unicode strings `u'xxx'` into strings `'xxx'`

Comment: i want turn unicode u'xxx' into 'xxx'

Comment: Do you want to change the representation (how it looks when you print it) or do you want to encode the strings to ASCII, UTF-8, ...?

Comment: i want to store the content of res as it is except u',\xa0,\\n.So i could compare the words from res with my dictionary words.I had not given my dictionary in code

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove the u (as in unicode) in u'somestring'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855645/how-to-remove-the-u-as-in-unicode-in-usomestring)

Answer (score 0):

try to encode the unicode strings as 'utf-8'

```
res =[s.encode('utf-8') for s in res]
```

or if you prefer for loops

```
ascii_strings = []
for s in res:
   ascii_strings.append(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to remove `u''` when you print `res` (a list of Unicode strings). You could print each string individually:

```
for unicode_string in res:
    print unicode_string
```

The reason you saw `u''` is due to `print some_list` calling `repr(item)` on each item in the list and `u'..'` is Unicode string literal in Python:

```
>>> print [u'a']
[u'a']
>>> print repr(u'a')
u'a'
>>> print u'a'
a
```

Answer (score 0):

**List of str, unicode and int types**

```
>>> item_list = [ 'a', 3, u'b', 5, u'c', 8, 'd', 13, 'e' ]
>>> print item_list
['a', 3, u'b', 5, u'c', 8, 'd', 13, 'e']
```

**Convert unicode types to str types**

```
>>> item_list = [ str(item) if isinstance(item, unicode) else item for item in item_list  ]
>>> print item_list
['a', 3, 'b', 5, 'c', 8, 'd', 13, 'e']
```

**Convert str types to unicode types**

```
>>> item_list = [ unicode(item) if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in item_list  ]
>>> print item_list
[u'a', 3, u'b', 5, u'c', 8, u'd', 13, u'e']
```

str and unicode are both subclasses of **[basestring](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#basestring)**